# How is this version of the pearson correlation coefficient derived?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, population

After taking my first semester stats class I started getting more and more into statistics. Currently I've come across this version of the Pearson Correlation Coefficient. Comparing this formula to the formula presented on Wikipedia shows they're inconsistent. Further, I've seen at least 3 different ways to calculate it. Here's the link:

http://www.stat.wmich.edu/s216/book/node122.html and the formula therein:
[image]

How is this formula derived? Since it is dividing through by n I assume this particular version is for populations and also for discrete data. Am I correct?

Comment: In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient), you can see your formula, it is called the "alternative formula" there. If in your formula you multiply each term by $n$ you'll get that formula. This formula is derived by the alternative way to compute the (co)variances (which build up the "classic" formula of $r$).

Comment: So, your formula is equivalent to the "classic" one. And no, you are not right supposing that it is for population or for discrete data.

Comment: @ttnphns Well, if the bottom part is divided by n instead of (n-1) doesn't that indicate it is the population standard deviation being divided in the denominator?

Comment: (Cov)variance formula based on `n-1` is the unbiased estimate; based on `n` is biased maximul likelihood estimate. So both are valid estimates. The true population parameter is not known since we don't have the whole population at hand.